# Changed guest server's VB network from "Host-only adapter" to "bridged adapter" now unreachable

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, hosts

I was previously using "host-only adapter" for the internet connection to my VirtualBox machine because I was in an area with no internet. Now that I'm on wi-fi I want to switch to the bridged adapter so I can use the local network and also download things to the server. But after changing this it's unreachable.

I tried this:

1. On the box, released and re-asked for dhcp (`dhclient -r`, `dhclient`)
2. Shutdown the VB guest server and restarted

Neither one works. It's still unreachable (although the guest server itself can reach the internet) from the host computer.